# Can 3 values (consecutive) of a vector be sorted using this method?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, iterator

So I'm trying to swap 3 values of a vector of ints by rotating them leftwards , i.e. ABC->BCA
And i want to make this happen by using iterators. Also, i know the iterator referring to C.
So what i did was I made the following function:

```
void xsort(vector<int>::iterator& it)
{
    int temp= *(it-2);
    *(it-2)= *(it-1);
    *(it-1)= *(it);
    *(it)=temp;
    return;
}
```

My question is that if this function will correctly do what I wish? And if not , how will I achieve the required?

```
funk(vector<int>& vec , vector<int>::iterator i)
{
    ...
    ...
    xsort(i);
    ...
}
```

Second question: If we have a function named funk having the given arguments , and if this function is the one calling xsort() by passing to it, the iterator 'i' (funk is called by the main() ) . Would this still change the values of the vector as desired?
Note: In the arguments of funk(), the vector has the reference operator associated with it while the iterator 'i' doesn't.

Comment: _"My question is that if this function will correctly do what I wish?"_ Have you tested it? What happens? _"Now even if that function works in that case , i don't think it will in this case. And I'm confused about this."_ I'm confused, too. I can't figure out what you're asking here. Can you rephrase?

Comment: You can use subscript notation, such as `it[-2]` instead of `*(it - 2)`.

Comment: The first function looks OK, like cdhowie I have no idea what your second question is about.

Comment: do you insist on using vector? such operations are much easier using lists

Comment: @HikmatFarhat There were other operations which i had to perform which required random access , so i chose vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate), as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    std::vector vec {'A', 'B', 'C'};
    std::rotate(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend()-1, vec.rend());
    for(auto const &el :vec) std::cout<< el <<" ";
}
So the out is -> B C A
```

If u have two functions and u want to pass a var by reference to one of them, the second will be called by the first and will take the same argument by ref., then the answer is yes if any one of them changes the var, the original one will change.